# Не возможно или невозможно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

> – Есть возможность отрубить преролл в окне предпросмотра видоса в админке ?
>
> – На данный момент это вообще не возможно.

В одно слово или нет?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае — слитно.

А вообще, часто возникают проблемы с написанием этого слова. Нужно ли его писать слитно? Или следует писать раздельно? Могут встречаться оба варианта написания данного слова. В каждом конкретном случае нужно смотреть на его смысл в предложении. Если по смыслу данное слово является синонимом слов «запрещено», «нельзя», то его слудет писать слитно. Если же оно служит для выражения противопоставления в предложении, то его необходимо писать раздельно.
(http://pishitegramotno.com/stati/nevozmozhno-kak-pishetsya.html)

Ответ Грамоты:
Вопрос № 221977
Обязательно ли слитное написание наречий "немало", "невозможно"
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
В некоторых контекстах возможно раздельное написание: не мало, а много... не возможно, а наверняка...